# Disabling the logs from Tensorflow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using the following code to see If I am able to stop TF/KERAS from producing logs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

Here you may see that I have used `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` in my code to disable logs.

> Num GPUs Available:  1 Executing op MatMul in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 tf.Tensor( [[22. 28.]
> [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)

Is there any way I can disable TF/KERAS to print `Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line and you can get rid of the ops device placement messages:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```